# Javascript / Mute video sound at start

Tags: javascript, html, video, mute

I'm working on a webpage with videos.
When refraishing the page, I want to randomly start a muted video. After rolling on it, the video is unmute.

I've already done the randomly videos javascript but I can't mute the video...
When I launch the page, the video starts with sound...

Here is my code :

```
 <div id="mixmen" onmouseover="play()" onmouseout="mute()" onclick="location.href='http://ap-mixmen.com/','_blank'" >

<div class="video">


<section id="videos">

<video id="videos" preload="none" style="height:100%"> 
<source src="imgs/mixmen.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>

<video id="videos" preload="none" style="height:100%"> 
<source src="imgs/mixmen2.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>

<video id="videos" preload="none" style="height:100%"> 
<source src="imgs/mixmen3.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>

<video id="videos" preload="none" style="height:100%"> 
<source src="imgs/mixmen4.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>


</section>


</div>


<script>

(function () {
                "use strict";
                document.getElementById("videos").muted = true;
                var videosSection = document.getElementById("videos");
                var videosSectionClone = videosSection.cloneNode();
                var videos = videosSection.getElementsByTagName("video");
                var randomVideo = videos.item(Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length)).cloneNode(true);
                randomVideo.removeAttribute("controls");
                randomVideo.setAttribute("preload", "auto",);
                videosSectionClone.appendChild(randomVideo);
                videosSection.parentNode.replaceChild(videosSectionClone, videosSection);
                randomVideo.play();


})();

var videosSection = document.getElementById("videos");

function play()
{ 
  video.muted = false; 
}

function mute()
{ 
  video.muted = true; 
}



</script>

</div>
```

Do you know why it doesn't work ?

Answer (score 0):

try adding muted to the video tag

Ex:

Comment: Thank you for helping ! I'va already try this and it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "muted" to the video tags.

```
<video id="videos" preload="none" muted style="height:100%"> 
<source src="imgs/mixmen.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping ! I'va already try this and it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Hi First section id must be different to your video tags then your video tags also must have a different id and finally you apply the "muted=true" to your selected element . If you want to mute all videos on the page load you can access to them by tag name then apply the mute as follow :

```
const videos= [...document.getElementsByTagName('video')];
videos.forEach((video) => { video.muted = true });
```

Comment: Thank you for helping !
Can you tell me exactly where i have to put this ? I'm really a noobie...

Comment: What do you want to do , mute all the videos on page load or just mute the on playing ?

Comment: I want to launch the video automaticaly without sound and when you roll on the video, the sound starts

Comment: just after var videos = videosSection.getElementsByTagName("video"); 
add this 
videos.forEach(function(video){
                video.muted = true;
  });
and don't forget to change ids

Comment: Thank you for answering ! Unfortunatly, It doesn't work. The video doesn't start, there is a white space.

Here is the code :

Comment: Argh code is too long...
When i delete videos.forEach(function(video){ video.muted = true; }); the video starts

Comment: I put it on internet : http://atlantispublicite.com/index2.html
You will see that video doesn't start (first at the left)

Comment: you didn't put  the line where i said, i also advise you to change the ids, i forgot to tell you to delete this line **document.getElementById("videos").muted = true;**
[See the image](https://i.imgur.com/pkcbme4.png)

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me ! I did what you said but it still doesn't work. I update my file : http://atlantispublicite.com/index2.html

Comment: here you can find the working code i modified, good luck !
 https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FRMXL00FHQPR

Comment: Thank you veeeery veeeery much it works fine !!! :)))
You saved me !
Regards,
Thibault